# nginx proxy_pass and virtual hosts within LAN returns 404

Tags: nginx, lan, mamp

I hope this makes sense. Basically, I have set up a local server on my MAC using nginx, with these rules for the proxy_pass:

```
    location /engine/rest {
        proxy_pass http://somedomain:9080/engine/rest;
    }

    location /engine/ {
        alias /data/www/pln/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        root /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
```

I also have a MAMP running to serve a virtual host so that I can access it from my Windows PC, using this config:

```
   <VirtualHost *:9090>

       DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
       ServerAdmin root@localhost
       ServerName localhost

       <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/>
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
```

And I've added this hosts config in the Windows PC:

```
   192.168.1.3 machost
```

But when I access my application on the Windows, it returns 404 errors for any resources from    `http://machost:9090/engine/test/someurl`, which should have been passed in the nginx rules.

I guess I need to add a vhost config in the nginx environment too, but I'm not a server guy (obviously). What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you should change the default.conf with some like that

```
server {
    listen localhost:9080; #your public ip or some other which you want nginx listen
    server_name _;  
    location / {
              proxy_pass http://locahost; #site which is on apache
                }
   }
```

I am not sure to understand the question, I am really sorry if my answer is not correct.